# How do I set preferences for the Guake Terminal?

Tags: command-line, guake

Just installed guake - terminal emulator.

How can I get to preferences to customize it?

I don't seem to have any if the normal menu's available.

I searched everything on their help site to no avail.

I use Ubuntu 11 (now Ubuntu 16 in 2016)

Comment: On my system, I have an icon in the Gnome Panel for Guake, and right-clicking this icon gives me a menu that includes "Preferences", which brings up a big property page with 5 tabs.  If you don't have a launcher icon for it, then you may need to use an alternate method as suggested below.

Comment: That doesn't work for me now in 2016 BUT I _can_  right-click from anywhere in the quake terminal itself as shown in my answer below.

Comment: Great.  TBH, it's been so long I had totally forgotten about Quake.  Somewhere along the way, I didn't install it and forgot it.  Thanks for the reminder. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### 2016(v16.04) Update: Easiest way is to right-click from within Quake !

[image]

Guake preferences can also be set via a separate program.

1. Start it from the HUD:

   -->
   [image: screenshot]
2. OR, press <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> and type `guake-prefs` and press Enter
3. OR, open a terminal and type `guake-prefs`

Comment: Ahhh, better than my own answer, great!

Comment: I would like to set guake preferences by a script. Is this possible without clicking in the gui? Where does guake save it's preferences? Can I set it with gsettings or dconf in the cli? Is there a config file I can export or anything similar?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that you use [Dconf Editor](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) `dconf-editor` (which deprecate gnome's configuration editor) like this:

[image: screenshot]

Which can be installed with `dconf-editor` and found like this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Another alternate answer to this is

1. Open `Terminal` from GUI for command line using `Alt + Ctrl + T`
2. `guake -p`

Comment: didn't work.  requires me to `sudo apt-get install quake` even though I have it already and am using it.  I am not doing the `apt-get install` suggested in case it messes up my current quake.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I think you've typed quake instead of guake